# Really don't know how to calculate time complexity of below code

Tags: time-complexity

below is my brute force way to implement "longest common substring"

```
class Solution {
public:    
/**
* @param A, B: Two string.
* @return: the length of the longest common substring.
*/
int longestCommonSubstring(string &A, string &B) {
    // write your code here
    if (A.length() > B.length()) {
        return longestCommonSubstring(B, A);
    }
    string str1, str2;
    int maxlen = 0, len = A.length();
    for (int i = 0; i < len; i++) {   //1 * len
        for (int j = 1; j <= len - i; j++) {  //   
            str1 = A.substr(i, j);
            for (int m = 0; m <= B.length() - j; m++) {
                str2 = B.substr(m, j);
                if (str1 == str2) {
                    maxlen = max(maxlen, j);
                }
            }
         }
     }
return maxlen;
}
```

}

However I was stuck on time complexity of this one, especially for third loop. I know first two loops should be O(N ^ 2), N is A's size. However I don't how to involve third loop. Could anyone give me the calculation approach ? Thanks very much

Comment: Is the size of `B` considered a constant, or is its size also part of the problem size?  If the former, its easy; if the later, then the problem size (N) can't just be the length of A.

Comment: Start from the worst case: what if you removed the `- j` in the innermost loop?  That would be an upper bound on your complexity.